# Change event fires jquery handler but not javascript handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I am seeing a weird behavior that when I use `addEventListener`, `change` event handler doesn't get fired on the select with `display: none;`. On the other hand, when I use jQuery, it does fire. What's the trick that allows jQuery to do that and how do I make it work in plain JavaScript?

Here is code that shows the example.

```js
// This doesn't work
document.getElementById("notDisplayedSelect").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  $("#output").text("When select is hidden events still fire: new value = " + $(this).val());
});

/*
// This works
$("#notDisplayedSelect").change(function (e) {
    $("#output").text("When select is hidden events still fire: new value = "+ $( this ).val());
}); 
*/

$("#setValue").click(function() {
  $("#notDisplayedSelect").val("3").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
#notDisplayedSelect {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="notDisplayedSelect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<span id="output">I show selected value</span>
<button id="setValue">Select third option in the hidden select</button>
```

Comment: How can you change something that isn't visible?

Comment: You can if you use `select` under the hood, while displaying a more complicated custom control. A good example is here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with the select element being hidden.  If you remove the "display: none" from your jsFiddle, you'll notice no difference.  The issue is with how you are firing the event, as others have mentioned below.  Check here for how to fire the event properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: @VCode, I was able to make it work, thanks for suggestion. I'll accept your answer with `dispatchEvent` if you add it, since it was your idea.

Comment: @ShalomAleichem, by all means, if VCode puts an answer you should accept it. Otherwise,if there is an answer that helped you should accept it to guide future readers of this post

Comment: In fairness to @AmmarCSE, please accept his answer.  It has the complete explanation of the problem and the correct solution already.  No point in duplicating the work he's already done.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) docs

> Any event handlers **attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods**
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs.

When you do

```
 $("#notDisplayedSelect").val("3").trigger("change");
```

only handlers attached with `on()` or `change()` will be triggered.

Apparently, this does not include handlers attached with the native

`addEventListener("change", function (e) {...});`

If you want to trigger the handler attached by native javascript, you can do

```
var event = new CustomEvent("change");
document.getElementById("notDisplayedSelect").dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Update**
Workaround for above in IE

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("change", true, true);
document.getElementById("notDisplayedSelect").dispatchEvent(event);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q2rwcaja/16/)

See [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to tweak it to make it work in IE though (CustomEvent doesn't work there)

Comment: @ShalomAleichem, did you use document.CreateEvent instead? Let me know so I can update my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, I used `document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")`, please see the Solution section of my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a handler using jQuery, jQuery keeps information about this handler in its internal memory, in addition to adding it as a browser event listener. Then when you call `trigger("change")`, it just calls these handlers itself, rather than going through the browser.

In the browser, it makes no sense to change an invisible element, because the `change` event is associated with user interaction.